# PrimeFaces 5.2 InputMask will not execute onfocus

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am currently experiencing an issue with the [`<p:inputMask>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml) component.  I would like the onfocus event to select the input value, for usability issues.  I can get this same code to work when the input is an inputText but when I change to inputMask, the event does not seem to fire:

```
<p:inputMask mask="9?9999999"
             onfocus="this.select();"
             id="formLine21"
             value="#{managedBean.formBean.line21}"/>
```

It appears that the focus might be working, but that the selection is being overridden by something in the prime-faces control.  The value will select on focus very briefly and then unselect again.  I can only duplicate that effect in Firefox however.  In IE nothing appears to happen at all.

When I removed the optional "?" from the pattern the select value on focus worked, even without the onfocus attribute and JavaScript.  That is how the control works.

After much experimentation i have isolated the exact behavior that reproduces the error.  When the optional mask indication is present "?" and you put in a value that is less than the total number of allowable chars, the select on focus breaks, because as soon as the field is focused, the cursor is placed at the end of the selection, and the select is lost to the active blinking cursor.

Now I am left to wonder if this is an intentional design decision and if I am simply SOL.  I really need variable input, select on focus, and numerical input masking.

Comment: You should add this behavior on the primefaces forum. Since you narrowed it down.

Comment: Nice investigation, compliments so far. But… Posting this in the PrimeFaces forum will not help much (if at all). It is a peer support forum just like Stackoverflow. And there is a lot still to investigate. Things like trying a newer PF release (which might include a newer jquery ui and corresponding plugins) or even try RC's or 'trunk'), looking at the PF source for the inputmask component, specifically the clientside js (the intentional design or not can most likely be seen there), try adding a small delay and more

Comment: Unfortunately I am using the latest freely available version of PF which is PF 5.2 - What is RC's or 'trunk'?  Are these JS toolkits or component libraries?